# How do I get this 4-bit synchronous up/down binary counter to work?

Tags: digital-logic, counter, proteus, binary

I'm trying to get this circuit using a SN74HC191 chip to work but it's producing no output to the LEDs.

My current setup so far is:

[image]

What makes this more difficult is that the datasheet for the SN74HC191 has no truth/function table so I'm not sure which switches needs to be high/low. Please could anyone provide some help?

Thank you!

Edit: [This is the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc191.pdf).

I have now actually found [another datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc190.pdf) with a truth table. However, even with the same H/L settings for "Count up", it still does not produce any LED output.

Comment: There are not pull-down resistors at the switches and no series resistors at the LEDs. Can the IC supply enough current for the LEDs?

Comment: Have you applied +5v to Vcc pin? And connected GND pin to the supply as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LEDs are backwards, and require ~330Ohm resistors for protection.

Also, your enable signal (~CTEN) is floating.  Tie this to ground to enable the outputs.  Tie all other logic inputs (D0-D3, D/~U, ~PL) that you're controlling with the DIP switch to ground with ~4.7k resistors so that they aren't floating, too.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This shows all the info you need for a truth table.

74HC' Ron driver resistance is approx 50 ohms at 5V to estimate your LED current, add suitable R for current limit. eg if Blue = 3V , then 2Vdrop/10mA=200 Ohm, so use 150 ohms. then verify voltage drop on R=150 = 1.5V. thus Voh =4.5V.  (for example).

Include cap across Vss to Vdd for 5V and twisted pair for Clk //Gnd if using long wires.

- Observe LED cathode towards gnd.  (-ve is always the reflector cup side and may have marking (flat edge on body)

[image]

- Never leave CMOS input floating.  Pullup 1M to 10k.
- Beware of ESD damage.